# Macro code to read value of a cell in Excel & enter a given value in a second sheet on corresponding row

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Looking for some help with a fairly basic excel macro to read a value in a cell on one Excel sheet and then find that value in a second sheet and enter a pre-defined value into a specified cell in that row.

To break it down...

1. Read the value of a given cell in sheet_1 (this will be an ID number)
2. Go to sheet_2, find the ID number in column_a
3. Go to a given column in that row
4. Write a pre-defined value into the cell

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may point you in the right direction:

```
Sub FindID()

Dim ID_Number As String
Dim col As Integer
Dim rw As Integer
Dim WS As Worksheet

Set WS = Activeworkbook.Sheets("sheet_2")

ID_Number = Activecell.Value 'reads value of ID_Number in WS 1; assumes you have selected the ID_Number you want to work with

With WS
    .Activate
    .Range("A1").Activate
End With

WS.Range("A:A").Cells.Find(What:=ID_Number, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _  'finds ID_Number in WS 2
                         LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                         MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

rw = Activecell.Row

col = 'whatever column you want to look at, expressed as an integer; A=1, B=2,...

WS.Cells(rw, col).Value = ID_Number 'write ID_Number to cell

End Sub
```

You can use the "Find" method of the "Cells" object to search for the column you want to look at, as well, if you want to make your code more dynamic.

Comment: thanks for your speedy response.

When I try and compile the above code I get a 'named argument' error against "SearchFormat:=False"

Comment: @In_Need_Of_Macro_Assistance I believe the reason you are getting the error is that "Find" is searching every cell 'after' the ActiveCell in "WS", but there is no ActiveCell.  I just edited the code to activate the "WS" object before using the "Find" method, and fix the issue (works on my computer).  The other option is to get rid of the arguments in "Find" (so it reads WS.Range("A:A").Cells.Find(ID_Number)), but I thought you'd find it useful to see how "Find" really works.

Comment: @In_Need_Of_Macro_Assistance try the answer code I submitted again, but for the "Find" method use: WS.Range("A:A").Cells.Find(ID_Number).Activate.  Typo from my last comment.  If you need to replace variables or sheet names, that's OK.  Check your 'col' value as well (115 corresponds to column "DK"...just double-checking this is what you want).

Comment: Yes, column DK is correct. Things are starting to work, but there are a few bugs and erratic behaviours with the row in which it places the text string into. The odd behaviour seems to arise depending on which cells are active in sheet 2 before the macro is run.

I’ve updated the current code I am using into this thread. Perhaps the full search functionality would help resolve some of the bugs?

Comment: The bugs I’ve described with the pre-defined "Accept" value being written to the wrong row on sheet_2 seem to occur if sheet_2 is active at the point the macro is initiated rather than sheet_1. The macro will be initiated by clicking a button in sheet_1 but I would like to eliminate this bug and understand why it is occurring. Any ideas?

Comment: @In_Need_Of_Macro_Assistance couple of things: if you are going to set multiple variables for different worksheets, it's better to 'dim' variables for "WS_1", "WS_2", etc. and use those, instead of setting a variable, and then re-setting.  Also, you might try specifying the object path for the range in the second line, something like: Activeworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A6").Value.  
Finally, don't forget to vote up, or "Accept", if my answer helped out! :)